# CSS flexbox fully collapse all empty children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given an html structure that follows the schema in this snippet, how can I fully collapse the empty "col" divs, leaving the content divs equally sized (two columns in this case)?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the empty elements with the `.col` class by using the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo class.

I've chosen to change the `flex` attribute on the, so they will shrink, but you can also set `display: none`, or force `max-width: 0`, etc...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

.col:empty {
  flex: 0 1 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick reply Ori, indeed I had considered the empty pseudo selector.  Unfortunately in my real scenario they arent truly empty like I depicted here, but have some empty tags created by Angular.  I appreciate the quick reply tho!

Comment: If you're using angular, add a class to the `.col` if the model says it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the content to a nuclear width of 100vw with a max-width of 100%.  The caveat is that this is not compatible with any version of IE.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <p class="content">Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use good-old table display props if IE support is needed.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 500px;
  display: table;
}

.row {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content">Foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content">Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```